# Unable to replace specific line from file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have around 100 scripts in as many folders, all of which have a specific value for my variable config_list. I want to edit its 14th line from

`for i in 10-35-5  8-35-7`
to
`for i in $config_list`

where, config_list is a string which has the format of list of such triplets of numbers, i.e. `echo $config_list` gives output like:

```
18-32-28 20-32-26 25-32-21 27-32-19  
16-32-27 18-30-27 25-32-18 28-30-17  
16-30-27 16-32-25 18-32-23 18-34-21 19-31-23 20-30-23 25-32-16
```

etc. depending upon the current folder.

Hence, if `config_list` is `0-20-0 3-15-2 5-10-5 6-8-6 7-6-7` for a particular folder, then the 14th line of the script should be (expected output):
`for i in 0-20-0 3-15-2 5-10-5 6-8-6 7-6-7`

Each list is unique for each folder and may have anywhere from 1 to 8 such triplets. So basically, I'm trying to change the argument of the for loop for each of the separate script files which are in correspondingly different folders, using another script.

I tried using

`sed -i "14s/.*/for i in $config_list/" $dest/script.sh`
where, dest is the destination folder prefix and is properly defined.

When I run the script over my entire set of folders, I'm getting the following error sometimes:
`` sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command ``
and sometimes I'm not even getting any error, but the destination files aren't changed.

I have used the exact same syntax for changing another line in the same file in the same script and that works perfectly in all cases but this doesn't.

I used `sed -i "2s/.*/#PBS -N li-cap-$num/" $dest/script.sh` to change the 2nd line from
`#PBS -N li-cap-50`
to
`#PBS -N li-cap-$num`

Any idea what's wrong?

Edit 1: I tried:
`sed -i "/for/c\for i in $config_list" $dest/script.sh`

and I got the following error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown command:` -'`

Edit 2: Here's the definition of $config_list:
`config_list=$(ls -l | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}')`

Comment: So your `$config_list` contains newline characters? How do you set it? What is the _exact_ output of `printf -- '%s\n' "$config_list"`? Also, what operating system is this? There are many different `sed` implementations.

Comment: Hang on, also show us the expected output. Are you expecting the literal `$config_list` or are you expecting the variable's value in the output?

Comment: @terdon no it doesn't contain any newline characters.  
```echo $config_list``` gives something like ```18-32-28 20-32-26 25-32-21 27-32-19```

The output of ```printf -- '%s\n' "$config_list"``` does put newlines in between the elements of ```$config_list```

The expected output is the variable's value not the literal $config_list. The value of $config_value changes from folder to folder. This sed is inside a for loop that loops over all folders.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add this information. We need to see the expected output, we need to see how you set the variable's value and we need to see that it doesn't contain newlines since the current version of your question shows that it does. Also, check which folder is giving you the error. What's different about it?

Comment: I added the desired info. The folders which have more than one triplet are giving errors but the ones with only one triplet are successful. However, I cannot see a pattern as to when I'm getting an error or when it just simply doesn't happen without an error.

But the error in edit 1 is consistent for all folders except the ones with only one triplet.